# How to align html div elements horizontally in popover bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. I want to align two div elements horizontally in a popover but I don't know the exact class to apply the style for setting the property `display: inline-block;`. Any idea how can I achieve that?

I tried wrapping them with another div and setting this property to `inline-block` to parent div but did not work.

```
$('#tag-input').popover({
            container: 'body',
            trigger: "manual",
            html: "true",
            animation: true,
            content: "<div>First row</div><div>Second row</div>"
        });
```

[image: Illustration of element alignment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply wrap the two divs in a div with `class="row"`. Then you can add `class="col-xs-6"` to each of them, so they each take up 50% width of the popover.

[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19694/)

```
$('#tag-input').popover({
    container: 'body',
    trigger: "hover",
    position: "bottom",
    html: "true",
    animation: true,
    content: "<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6'>First row</div><div class='col-xs-6'>Second row</div></div>"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your responese. But I have another situation where the number of divs is unknown. They are created dinamically. So i have to separate the space equally for each of them. Any idea how can I do that, because as you explained above the col size is not dynamic.